# React Typescript : Initialize Default Value of Object Array Inside Another Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an Object named Parent and it has an array of another object named Child and I dont know how to give its initial value when called in state of a component class.
I tried to casting it with `as Child[]` but it still doesn't work

Parent :

```
export interface Parent {
    id: string,
    child : Child[]
}
```

State in Component

```
interface State {
    parent: Parent
}
```

How I initialize the value

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        parent: {
            id: "",
            child: [] as Child[]
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: What you have is correct, and the `as Child[]` is unecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type of your state in class definition:

[View in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAYQAtgAbAEzgG9S4BcSihBIAXHADOMKFQDmAblIBfclRp0GcAAooi1Xv0HBOE6bMpyANEYFo2XOBNYdOAbQC6KitVr00jADKMCg0hoJwYHpI1BK6+jDe6n5a2jhgkoaqpGjsKJKZALIAnky4kJQx8EgAHjSUnJnI6DAAdGXgEJXUADxpEBlWcMGhSAB84YJoXeYArhjQABRg6ZJxqwCUkxECkrNgtMubSjuCMGySrdKjcAC826eCUQkSfI-vcCYSAETfNh+PeyuCSeAQAejBcGKEFmcE4XXw8BYKAAbowYBA4UhMFR0cUDnBbADiYIIXAYPikJI0LIwPAqJhaJkRmFkpoAp9KOSLlcQjQie9VILyETshF9JxDls3o8ydDYci0ZyaOx2MBJDENYT3tNKJIIOwkK12BA5ItzureaNWs8qhslALBEQYLMoFzFj1OMAUWNWn6emCvT6NqLyNkgA)

```js
export interface Parent {
    id: string,
    child : Child[]
}
interface State {
    parent: Parent
}
interface Props {
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            parent: {
                id: "",
                child: []  // you don't have to define type 
                           // typescript infers State interface in this.state
            }
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (<div>...</div>)
    }

}
```

> Within TypeScript, React.Component is a generic type (aka
>   React.Component), so you want to provide it with
>   (optional) prop and state type parameters:

Read more in [typescript-cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#class-components)